# output of oddlines in sed not appearing on separate lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following file:

```
>A6NGG8_201_I_F
line2 
>B1AK53_719_S_R
line4
>B1AK53_744_D_N
line5
>B7U540_205_R_H
line6 
>B7U540_354_T_M
line7
```

where I want to print out all odd lines. I can do this by:

```
$ sed -n 1~2p file
>A6NGG8_201_I_F
>B1AK53_719_S_R
>B1AK53_744_D_N
>B7U540_205_R_H
>B7U540_354_T_M
```

and so I want to store the number in each line as a variable in bash, however I run into a problem - storing the result of sed puts the output all on one line:

```
#!/bin/bash

line1=$(sed -n 1~2p)
echo ${line1}
```

in which the output is:

```
>A6NGG8_201_I_F >B1AK53_719_S_R >B1AK53_744_D_N >B7U540_205_R_H >B7U540_354_T_M
```

so that when I do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

line1=$(sed -n 1~2p)
pos=$(echo ${line1} | awk -F"[__]" 'NF>2{print $2}')
echo ${pos}
```

I get

```
201
```

where I of course want:

```
201
719
744
205
354
```

How do I store the result of sed into separate lines so that they are processed properly when piped into my awk statement? I see you can use the `/a`notation, however when I tried `sed -n '/1~2p/a' file`this does not work in my bash script. Thanks

Comment: just quote it: `echo "$line1"`. But you may want to approach the cleaning part differently: what is the logic of this `-F"[__]"` 'NF....`?

Comment: thanks! oh and the logic is that it grabs strings between two underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, you need to quote the variable to make this happen:

```
echo "${line1}"
```

instead of

```
echo ${line1}
```

However, you can directly say:

```
awk -F_ 'NR%2 && NF>2 {print $2}' file
```

This will process even lines and, in them, print the 2nd field on `_` separated, just if it there are more than 2 fields.

---

From [tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28944258/1983854) I observe that a FASTA file can contain a different format. If so, I guess you will still want to get the ID in the lines starting with ">". This can be translated as:

```
awk -F_ '/^>/ && NF>2 {print $2}' file
```

---

See an example of how quoting preserves the format:

The file:

```
$ cat a
hello
bye
```

Read it into a variable:

```
$ var=$(< a)
```

`echo` without quoting:

```
$ echo $var
hello bye
```

Let's quote!

```
$ echo "$var"
hello
bye
```

Comment: thanks @fedorqui. I will change my filtering logic based on your post too.

Comment: Nice! If you start using `sed` and `awk` in different places, piping one's result to the other, chances are that you can join both commands :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the header lines out of a FASTA file, your problem statement is wrong -- the data between the headers could be more than one line.  You could simply do

```
sed -n '/^>/!d;s/^[^_]*//;s/_.*//p' file.fasta
```

to get just the second underscore-delimited field out of each header line; or equivalently, in Awk,

```
awk -F _ '/^>/ { print $2 }' file.fasta
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, or at least a near-duplicate; there are many beginner-level questions about FASTA processing here.